# Input range not moving in javascript

Tags: javascript

[image: screenshot of slider]

I'm trying to move the slider on START button click.

```
function timer(){
    var slider = document.getElementById("slider")
        slider.setAttribute("value",counter)
        slider.addEventListener("change", function(){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.value;
    counter = parseInt(this.value);
});}
```

I can increment the counter, using setInterval on every second to display the year.
But, I am not able to move the slider according to the year value

I don't intend to use jQuery. Is it possible to do only using pure JS?

Code for slider :

```
1900<input type="range" id="slider" min="1900" max="2015" value="1900">2015
```

Code for button:

```
<button onclick="mytimer = setInterval(timer,1000)">START</button>
<button onclick="clearInterval(mytimer)">STOP</button>
```

Comment: Where's the code for the start button click?

Comment: @tymeJV I have edited to add the code for start button click. Thanks

Comment: You should also add the `timer` function code.

Comment: @JCOC611 added Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the `change` function outside the `timer` - you dont need it in there. And then in your timer, actually SET the value!

```
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
slider.addEventListener("change", function(){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.value;
    counter = parseInt(this.value);
});

function timer(){
    slider.value = parseInt(slider.value) + 1; //increment;
}
```

And, stop using inline JavaScript - it clutters the HTML and makes the JS harder to understand at a glance:

```
var mytimer = null;
function startTimer() {
    mytimer = setInterval(timer,1000)
}

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(mytimer);
}

<button onclick="startTimer()">START</button>
<button onclick="stopTimer()">STOP</button>
```

Preferably you'd even remove the `onclick` and switch everything to `addEventListener` - but the above is a good start

Comment: Thanks, I clearly needed to separate html and javascript in the code. The slider now moves to max value once I click start button. Even if I move the slider to specific year it again moves to maximum year.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed this line : `slider.value = slider.value + 1` to `slider.value = parseInt(slider.value) + 1`
Does slider.value return string? It was not incrementing the value and instead returning the max value to slider.value until parseInt
Thank you

Comment: @linthum -- Yeah - appears it returns a string, so the `parseInt` is exactly what's needed!